# Extract and Rename different pictures in subfolders and copy them to another folder

Tags: powershell

This is my situation:
I have several pictures (90 pictures) named 'logo' located in:

```
C:\Folder\themes\Flo\psd
C:\Folder\themes\Agre\psd
....
```

I want to first extract each picture to another folder 'themes-logo2013' and rename each picture with the parent folder name this way:

```
logo-Flo.psd
logo-Agre.psd
....
```

End Result: Each picture will be located in:

```
C:\Folder\themes-logo2013\logo-Flo.psd
C:\Folder\themes-logo2013\logo-Agre.psd
...
```

Some people have suggested me to use PowerShell, but I have no notion on how to write a script for that and execute it.

Many thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\folder\themes -r -file | Where {$_.Path -match '\\psd$'} |
    Copy-Item -Dest {"C:\Folder\themes-logo2013\logo-$($_.Directory.Parent.Name).$($_.Directory.Name)\$_.Name"} -Whatif
```

Remove the `-whatif` when you satisfied the copy will work correctly.  Note the `-file` parameter is only available in V3 or higher but most folks have moved to V3 by now.  :-)

Comment: I have this error message:    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EmptyPipeElement

Comment: Missing closing '}' in statement block

Comment: Fixed the missing `}`.

Comment: Hi Keith! thanks I guessed the missing closing and executed the script, it shows no errors now but nothing has been modified...:)No files have been copied and renamed to the new folder!

Comment: Sorry I think this is the error: + show-command "\$_.Name"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation : (\.Name:String) [Show-Command], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NoCommand,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ShowCommandCommand

Comment: I did remove -whatif and executed the script. It doesn't show any errors and no results. The folder where I wanted to copy all the files and rename them is empty.

Comment: Hmm.  If you put the -Whatif back onto Copy-Item does the output show where it would be copying the files?

Comment: Well, I have no idea what's going wrong. I'm not sure if it's related to this script or any script. I think I can't run any script on PowerShell. I have the version 3 installed and enabled the script policy to run. It's my first time using PowerShell, there must be something I'm missing

Comment: The only requirement is to execute in elevated prompt `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` (or Unrestricted).  After that try a simple .ps1 file with `Get-Date` on the first line and see if you can execute that.

Comment: When I run Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned I have an error message: Permission denied. And when I run Get-ExecutionPolicy, I have Unrestricted..Get-Date works!:)